# How to dynamically initialize a 3d array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create a nxnxn size 3d array and fill it with 0.

Ex

if n = 3

output would be

```
[
  [
    [0],[0],[0]
  ],
  [
    [0],[0],[0]
  ]
  ,
  [
    [0],[0],[0]
  ]
],
[
  [
    [0],[0],[0]
  ],
  [
    [0],[0],[0]
  ]
  ,
  [
    [0],[0],[0]
  ]
],
[
  [
    [0],[0],[0]
  ],
  [
    [0],[0],[0]
  ]
  ,
  [
    [0],[0],[0]
  ]
]
```

Right now, I can manually do this using:

```
$array = array_fill(0,3,array_fill(0,3,array_fill(0,3,0)));
```

But, I need the array to be defined dynamically.

If n = 4, 3d array would be

```
$array = array_fill(0,4,array_fill(0,4,array_fill(0,4,array_fill(0,4,0)));
```

Comment: Thanks @PaulCrovella. Edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function hypercube($n, $obj=0) {
  for ($i = $n; $i; $i--) {
    $obj = array_fill(0, $n, $obj);
  }
  return $obj;
}
```

Note: `hypercube(3)` will make an array that is 3x3x3. Your example shows an array that is 3x3x3x1 (because of `[0]`. You can do `hypercube(3, array(0))` to get your sample.

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks @Amadan

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
function getNDimensionalArray($n)
{
    $x = $n;
    $value = array();
    while ($x) {
        $value = array_fill(0, $n, $value);
        $x--;
    }
    return $value;
}
```